# How do I submit more than one checkbox in an HTML form?

Tags: html, ruby, model-view-controller, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

This is a project for school, and so far I only know Ruby, Sinatra, HTML & CSS. I've looked online but only came across PHP and Javascript insturctions (which I'm not supposed to use yet).

I have a form for checkboxes, and although I can check off more than one, only one of the checkbox values gets posted. How do I get it so all of the checked off ones are passed?

Also, 'abbreviation' comes out nil for each state. Am I doing this wrong in my form? And if anything it just uses ONE of the abbreviations and adds it to every state. Finally, how do I make it so the checkboxes remain checked for the states users have already added in the past?

Here's some code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/states">
<h3>Northeast:</h3> <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name" value="Connecticut" name="abbreviation" value="CT"> Connecticut<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name" value="Deleware" name="abbreviation" value="DE"> Deleware <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name" value="Maine" name="abbreviation" value="ME"> Maine<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name" value="Maryland" name="abbreviation" value="MD"> Maryland<br>
```

```
require 'pry'
class StatesController < ApplicationController

  get '/states' do
    if logged_in?
        @user = current_user
        @states = current_user.states
      erb :'states/states'
    else
      redirect to '/login'
    end
  end


  get '/states/new' do
    if logged_in?
      erb :'/states/create'
    else
      redirect to '/login'
    end
  end

  post '/states' do
      if logged_in? && params[:state_name] != ""
        @state = State.create(:state_name => params[:state_name], :abbreviation => params[:abbreviation])
        # binding.pry
        @state.users << current_user
          if @state.errors.any?
              "Error, try again"
          else
            redirect "/states"
          end
      else
        redirect to "/states/new"
      end
    end


  get '/states/:id' do
    if logged_in?
      @state = State.find_by_id(params[:id])

        if @state != nil
          erb :'/states/show'
        else
          redirect to '/states'
        end
    else
      redirect to '/login'
    end
  end


  get '/states/:id/edit' do
    if logged_in?
      @state = State.find_by_id(params[:id])
      if @state && current_user
        erb :'states/edit'
      else
        redirect to '/states'
      end
    else
      redirect to '/login'
    end
  end


    patch '/states/:id' do
      @state = State.find_by_id(params[:id])
        if params[:state_name] != "" && @state.update(:state_name => params[:state][:state_name])
          @state.update(:state_name => params[:state][:state_name])
          redirect to "/states/#{@state.id}"
        else
          redirect to "/states/#{@state.id}/edit"
        end
    end

    delete '/states/:id/delete' do
      if logged_in?
        @state = State.find_by_id(params[:id])
          if @state && current_user
              @state.destroy
          end
        redirect to '/states'
      else
        redirect to '/login'
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your input tags each have 2 name properties. They should only have one.

Comment: And 2 `value` properties each.

Comment: But how would I differentiate between the two values when using a state_name in one of my views and the abbreviation in anothor view?

Comment: Please include **only** the action you are submitting this form on.

Comment: Another question, are you really hardcoding the state names and abbreviations in your form? You already have a table _states_. You should have all the state names and abs stored there and render the form by iterating on the list fetch from this table.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by only the action? I'm sorry, I am a new student and am very confused by all of this! That makes more sense, but I don't understand how the table _states_ would have each state name/abbreviation if I haven't entered it anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append `[]` to your name attribute to support array value i.e. more than one checked values:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name[]" value="Connecticut"> Connecticut<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name[]" value="Deleware"> Deleware<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name[]" value="Maine"> Maine<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name[]" value="Maryland"> Maryland<br>
```

Now on your server, you will see the checked values as `state_name: ['Connecticut', 'Maine', ...]`.

Note: You have specified the `name` and `value` attributes twice for each checkbox. I am using the first one.

Comment: Right but the point is that it posts the states in a numbered list to show which ones the user has been to. So I don't want an array. I just want it to post the individual state names for each one checked.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by that. Sorry, I'm a beginner!

Comment: Why do you wan't both the state name and abbreviation on the backend? Can't you figure out one from the another?

Comment: The state name is what is important, and that is the main attribute I am going for. However, I also want the state to be associated with an abbreviation so I can iterate over photos (which are named by the state's abbreviation) to display the correct state photo when viewing an individual state. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Here is my repository: https://github.com/cbronzo/travel_app ... I haven't commited my major updates because I've been playing around so much with this, but maybe this will give you a better idea of whats going on.

Comment: As per your [schema](https://github.com/cbronzo/travel_app/blob/master/db/schema.rb) you have state name and abbreviation both stored in database. So, you can easily find the full names if you have the abbreviations in your controller. No need to pass both of them from the form.

Comment: I guess that is where I am confused, how does the database have my state_names? Where have I written out each state name other than in the form?

Comment: Ok I just added my state controller to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I have always known that in html's forms the ids and names must be unique, unless you are working with radio buttons or in this case checkboxes.  Your code seems to be a bit overmade, meaning, you have 2 names and 2 values on each checkbox, and just the last one of both of them will work, so instead of this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name" value="Connecticut" name="abbreviation" value="CT"> Connecticut<br>
```

Try just having one of those attributes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="abbreviation" value="CT"> Connecticut<br />
```

Usually, <s>in</s> for php we would append a '[]' at the end of the name, and you will recieve an array of the values that were checked. But since you are using ruby, which I am a bit familiar to, I've seen the ruby developers like to be a bit more expressive in their code, and sometimes they do things like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="abbreviation[city_1]" value="CT">Connecticut<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="abbreviation[city_2]" value="DE">Delaware<br />
```

And so on.

You can see an example of it, [here](https://learn.co/lessons/sinatra-complex-forms-associations), even though I believe you can do it with the empty '[]', but just so you know I've been told that's the php-ish way to do it.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but I need to gather both params of "abbreviation" AND "state_name". If I just do name="abbreviation" then I lose out the state_name value. The idea is that the users can check off certain states and it will return the state names they checked off. I need the abbreviations to iterate through state pictures that are named by abbreviation.

Comment: Then you are looking this problem the wrong way.  You need to learn a bit more about html.  As we told you, only the last attribute you use is going to be send, non-negotiable, that is how html works.  I recommend you to read a bit more about html and how ids, classes, data-*, name, value and types work.

Comment: As I see it, you have some options: 1. Use javascript to achieve what you need, but you will have to learn about events, dom and ajax (using the new api fetch). 2. Remember that what I wrote is just an example you need to tailor it to your needs, you can do something like this: `<input type="checkbox" name="state_name[DE]" value="Delaware">Delaware<br />` and then process it with your server language.  You would lose the abbrevation part, but you know what those are. There maybe are another options, but it depends on how you want to resolve the current problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use only one name and value per input, like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="state_name" value="CT"> Connecticut<br><input type="checkbox" name="state_name" value="DE"> Deleware <br><input type="checkbox" name="state_name" value="ME"> Maine<br><input type="checkbox" name="state_name" value="MD"> Maryland
```

Check your POST array for state_name and their should be an array of all check-boxes selected.

Comment: Will still pass only one value to the server.